# How to do alias for this class

Tags: c++, class, templates, alias

I have some template classes in a namespace(n1). I'd like to have aliases of such classes in another namespace(n2). I have figured out for (1) and (3) cases, but couldn't do for (2).

```
//g++  7.4.0

#include <iostream>

// class itself
namespace n1
{
    // (1)
    template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1>
    class D
    {
        public:
        T1 t1;
        T2 t2;
    };
    
    // (2)
    template <typename PlatformType, typename IntermediateType, typename IndependentType>
    class D<D<PlatformType, IntermediateType>, IndependentType>
    {
        public:
        int t1 = 77;
        int t2 = 88;
    };
    
    // (3)
    template<>
    class D<int, float>
    {
        public:
        int t1 = 16;
        float t2 = 44.5f;
    };
    
}

// alias
namespace n2
{
    // (1) - OK
    template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1>
    using D = n1::D<T1, T2>;
    
    // (2) - Error
    template <typename PlatformType, typename IntermediateType, typename IndependentType>
    using D = n1::D<n1::D<PlatformType, IntermediateType>, IndependentType>;
    
    // (3) - OK
    template<typename T1 = int, typename T2 = float>
    using D = n1::D<T1, T2>;
}

int main()
{
    n2::D<int, float, double> a;
    std::cout << a.t1 << "\t" << a.t2;
}
```

The error is:

```
1376086875/source.cpp:48:76: error: conflicting declaration of template ‘template<class PlatformType, class IntermediateType, class IndependentType> using D = n1::D<n1::D<PlatformType, IntermediateType>, IndependentType>’
     using D = n1::D<n1::D<PlatformType, IntermediateType>, IndependentType>;
                                                                            ^
1376086875/source.cpp:44:28: note: previous declaration ‘template<class T1, class T2> using D = n1::D<PlatformType, IntermediateType>’
     using D = n1::D<T1, T2>;
```

Apparently, the compiler is confusing 2nd case with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the root cause is that you're confusing "template classes" and "class templates".

`template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1> class D` is a template. Every instantiation of the template is a class type, but this `n1::D` itself is a template and not a class.

The other `D`'s in `n1` are specializations of the first template, used when the `<T1,T2>` match.

In `n2` however you define 3 templates. This appears to be pointless. A single template seems enough since there's only one `n1::D` template to which it can refer.